# Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I created a new UWP MSTest Project and I added a reference to my main application.  When I build the solution, get the an error:

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Along with the conflicting files.  I checked the copy to local for the files and they are set to *Do not copy*.  Here's a sample of the error messages:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Payload contains two or more files with the same destination
>   path 'Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png'.
>   Source files: 
>   C:\Users\joe.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.1-beta1\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\TestPlatform.Universal\15.5\Redist\CommonConfiguration\neutral\Newtonsoft.Json.dll  App.Test    C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets  1747
>   Error     Payload contains two or more files with the same destination
>   path 'Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png'. Source files: 
>   E:\App.Test\Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png
>   E:\App\Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png   App.Test    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets  1747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the content file names are the same for the app itself and the test project. Even though you set them to **Do not copy**, they are still conflicting during the intermediate step of building the test project.

The simplest solution is to rename or delete the `Asset` `PNGs` inside the Test Project so that they do not conflict with your app itself.

### Newtonsoft.Json

Problem with `Newtonsoft.Json` is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162754/unit-teset-app-universal-windows-dont-compile-with.html) that has been reported to the Visual Studio team and the fix is now pending release.

The only workaround mentioned is the following by **Morten Nielsen**:

> As a workaround and if you can live with the v9 version the test
>   project ships with, you can add a direct assembly reference to the
>   Json.net lib that they use, instead of using the nuget reference.

Comment: OK. What about Newtonsoft.Json.dll?

Comment: I excluded the files from the project, still far from ideal.  Still trying to figure out the dll one.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer with the situation with Newtonsoft.Json