# Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path for Default.rd.xml file

Tags: unit-testing, uwp, reference, xunit

I was trying to do unit testing for UWP App. When I added target application reference in Test project, the following error is giving while running the test method

`Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path'Properties\Default.rd.xml'.Source files:   D:\Test\MyAppTesting\Properties\Default.rd.xml   D:\Test\MyApp\Properties\Default.rd.xml`

No error code was given.

[adding refernce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD0jE.png)

```
public class MyAppTesting
{
     [Fact]
     public async void PassingWinAppServiceTest()
     {
        
         AgendaService agendaService = new AgendaService();
         var memberModel = await agendaService.GetMemberDetailsById("234");

       Assert.False(String.IsNullOrEmpty(memberModel.MemberId.ToString()));
        
     }
```

Comment: You may want to add your code here so the contributors can provide clear solutions.

Comment: _throws error_ - what is the error?

Comment: @Fabio                                                                                                          Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path'Properties\Default.rd.xml'.  Source files:    
D:\Test\MyAppTesting\Properties\Default.rd.xml    
D:\Test\MyApp\Properties\Default.rd.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48362009/payload-contains-two-or-more-files-with-the-same-destination-path)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. You cannot simply exclude Default.rd.xml from a UWP project like you can with the Assets folder contents. This file is needed for .NET Native compilation. Has anyone else found a workaround for this specific conflict yet?

Comment: @96p did you solved this problem? I am facing the exact same error and not finding any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is to remove the **Default.rd.xml** file from the test project.

[Comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/482278/view.html) from the developer community for similar issue.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference) of Runtime Directive Configuration file,

> A runtime directives (.rd.xml) file is an XML configuration file that
> specifies whether designated program elements are available for
> reflection.

So, if reflection is not used in the test project then I believe, **Default.rd.xml** file can be safely removed from the test project.

Comment: This was the answer - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the NuGet, you need to add an existing project reference into the **unit test project**.

```
      [right click test project -> Add -> Reference-> select an existing project}
```

Then check your test project dependencies, Your existing project should be there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. In which way solves this the same destination path error?

Comment: @hansika this error occurs when I add the refernece  of my existing project